# Android WebView: shouldOverrideUrlLoading not called when user taps on local fragment identifier

Tags: android, html, android-webview, fragment, href

In my Android app I am using shouldOverrideUrlLoading to intercept when the user taps on  a link inside a local HTML page displayed in a WebView. I need to handle all cases, even when the link is to a local fragment identifier in the page, like href="samepage.html#fragment". But I see that in this case shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called. 
How could I handle this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify the content it would be best to use [window.onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) in your JavaScript. If needed you could use [addJavaScriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to "talk back" to your Java code.